# XSLT output text() of a node with tags in correct position

Tags: html, xml, xslt

So I have the following XML snippet...

I need to take this and put it into HTML. I want to say for each (section) print out the text of that section and if you see a (b) tag then output that tag around the word. But I'm not sure how to do this, because it seems I can only output the text() of section.

But I need to both output the text() of a node as well as manipulate the tags in that text().

This is the sample XML:

```
<body>
<section>
<title>Response</title>
<p> Some info here <b> with some other tags</b> or lists like <ol> <li>something</li>     </ol></p>
</section>
<section>Another section same format, sections are outputted as divs </section>
</body>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="body">

<xsl:for-each select='topic/body/section'>

<div class="section">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="title">
    <h2 class="title sectiontitle"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h2>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="p">
    [I dont know what to put here? I need to output both the text of the paragraph tag but also the html tags inside of it..]
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>


</div>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

Desired output - this block of html code for each section in the xml.

```
<div class="section">
<h2 class="title">Whatever my title is from the xml tag</h2>
<p> The text in the paragraph with the proper html tags like <b> and <u> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide sample input XML and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple. Write a template for every element you want to transform into HTML.

All nodes you did not write a template for are handled by the identity template, which copies them to the output unchanged:

```
<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <title> becomes <h2> -->
<xsl:template match="title"> 
  <h2 class="title">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </h2>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <section> becomes <div> -->
<xsl:template match="section">
  <div class="section">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <b> becomes <strong> -->
<xsl:template match="b">
  <strong>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </strong>
</xsl:template>
```

The XSLT processor handles all recursion for you (specifically, the `<xsl:apply-templates>` does that), so your input

```
<section>
  <title> some text </title>
  Some stuff there will have other tags like <b> this </b>
</section>
```

will turn into

```
<div class="section">
  <h2 class="title"> some text </h2>
  Some stuff there will have other tags like <strong> this </strong>
</div>
```

Since the identity template copies nodes unchanged, you don't need to write a template that "turns `<ul>` into `<ul>`". This will happen just fine on its own. Only elements that are not already HTML need their own template.

If you want to prevent certain things from showing up in the HTML, write an empty template for them:

```
<xsl:template match="some/unwanted/element" />
```

Comment: Oh wow I didn't realize it would output the text unless I specified...thanks so much!

Comment: @Kayla Yes, that's the default. Unless specified, XML elements output their `text()`. It's [one of the built-in rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule), also described [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/defaultrule.html#d3635e76).

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` would output an exact copy of the element (rather than `<xsl:value-of>` which is its textual value).

@Tomalak is right though about there being better ways to structure your XSLT in the first place.